# Console is showing output in just vertical lines

Tags: console

I am a C# beginner I tried to compile this code but the output is just vertical * line. I thought it was just a console problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void DrawPyramid(int n)
        {
            for(int i =1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   ");
                }
                for(int k=1;k<=2*i-1;k++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*"+" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[]args)
        {
            DrawPyramid(5);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify the language in the tags and in the subject please.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loops, you are using `Console.WriteLine()` which will allways print a line. So, in every iteration of this loop:

```
for(int k=1;k<=2*i-1;k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("*"+" ");
}
```

You are goin to print a `*`, a space and a new line. In the inner loops, you should use `Console.Write()`

Here is the 'fixed' `DrawPyramid()` method:

```
static void DrawPyramid(int n)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for(int k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

That being said, I am not 100% sure your question fits StackOverflow, as this distinction (between `Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()`) is a very basic topic and the documentation for it is more than abundant.